# In Linear Layout drawable left in Textview Giving more space between Text and Image

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout, drawable

I am using the `LinearLayout` with 2 `TextView`s. Assigning the `weight` to both the `TextView`s. One `TextView` is aligning at left and another at right corner.I give the `layout:gravity="right"` , So the text is aligning at right side. Drawable icon in the `TextView` aligning to the left and giving more space between text and icon.

I don't want use the `RelativeLayout` for this.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_apt_time"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/time"
            android:text="12 : 30 PM" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_apt_date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/time"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:text="23-Sept-2015" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you are setting `android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/time"` to both thats why its giving more space between text and icon

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drawableLeft use LinearLayout with horizontal orientation then put ImageView and TextView there.

EDIT: Here's an example.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:src="SOURCE"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="TEXT" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get ride of your margin left and right and your gravity, put a weightSum on your linearLayout and place your element with the weight

Answer (score 0):

Check your image carefully, I think it has some transparent part. As per your code, there will be no space in left.
And set gravity left for both Textviews if you don't want gap between text and image icon.